# Where can I find tracker-sparql-0.16?

Tags: nautilus

Im trying to build nautilus, but I need tracker-sparql-0.16.

Where can I find tracker-sparql-0.16 ?

Thank you.

Comment: May I first ask why you're trying to build `nautilus`? This seems a little ... overkill, if I may.

Comment: I am just curious and Im thinking about changing some things in Nautilus so it fits my needs better.

Comment: I am building bijiben and even I need this package.

Answer (score 1):

http://packages.debian.org/experimental/libtracker-sparql-0.16-0

http://packages.debian.org/source/experimental/tracker

But be careful. It has lot of dependencies and it may potentially break your system.  So unless you actually know what you are doing, its not recommended to install this.